# Trying to scrape table off Yahoo Finance. Need to drive the website in order to select correct time frame

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

I am trying to scrape the historic data table for 5 YEARS from https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/^NYA/history?p=^NYA. When you initially go onto the website it shows you a year. I want to click on the arrow or the date, then click on "5Y" then click done. Wait for the page to refresh then scrape all the information. This is my code so far which does not work.

I have done something similar before but the problem with this website is that there are no ids or names for the objects I want to click onto so I do not know how to select them. (Va(m)! is the one of the class for the drop down arrow and 5_Y is the data-value for the 5Y option)

```
chromedriver = "/Users/Esi/Downloads/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5ENYA/history?p=%5ENYA'
print url
driver.get(url)
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('Va(m)!'))
select.select_by_value("5_Y")
###Please add in a line to select Done button###
time.sleep(10)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")

tables = soup.findChildren('table')
#stock information in table indexed 1
print tables[1]
my_table = tables[1]

"""There are 7 columns Date -> Volume """
rows = my_table.findChildren(['th', 'tr'])

list_of_all =[]
for row in rows:
    cells = row.findChildren('td')
    for cell in cells:
        value = cell.string
        list_of_all.append(str(value.strip()))

# print list_of_all
num_rows = float(len(list_of_all))/float(7) 
# print num_rows    

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a go. It should let you load the data for 5 years as you requested for.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5ENYA/history?p=^NYA")

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "svg[class^=Va][data-icon=CoreArrowDown]"))).click()
item = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name=startDate]")))
item.clear()
item.send_keys("1/11/2013")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-test=date-picker-menu] button[class*=Bgc]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-reactid='25']"))).click()  #it should click on the apply button
#driver.quit()
```

Comment: After execution do take a look at the time period bar where you should see this: `Time Period:Jan 11, 2013 - Jan 11, 2018`.

Comment: This works so well, thank you again Shahin. I am now trying to click the APPLY button can you please help as there are no distinguishing names in the classes in the division it is in and it won't work. I have tried wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*=Bgc] button[data-reactid=25]"))).click()

Comment: Why do you want to click on that apply button. Have you tried manually if you can click on it? Btw, when the webpage loads  the data (i meant the one created by this script), have you scrolled down to see if all data are there? I've checked already. You don't need to click on that apply button at all.

Comment: Hi Shahin, on mine using your exact code i can only see up to jan 11, 2017 unless I press the apply button manually then all the other dates can be loaded. How do I press the apply button without doing so manually?

Comment: Hey, don't get me wrong. I didn't suggest you to click on that button manually. I wanted to know if that button works at all or not. In my end the data for five years gets loaded automatically that is why I told you to check that.

Comment: Thank you. Yes the apply button does work. Could you please help me write a line to click on it so that it can be part of the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163008/discussion-between-elizabethstudent-and-shahin).

Comment: I'll take a look into it and will drop here a message. Thanks.

Comment: Check the update. Code for clicking on apply button has been added. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried with the extended portion of code to see if it is able to click?

Comment: Thank you! I have and then I added some code so that it scrolls down the end of the table and then scrapes the whole table. Thank you for your help if you want to see what I have added I can post it.

Comment: No, that doesn't require. I just wanted to let you know that the extended portion of the code is able to perform a click on the apply button. That's it.

Comment: Hi Shahin, you were a massive help on this before and it has been working well for a long time however now the 'Apply' button won't be clicked and there is no mention of data-reactid=25 in the html. I have tried some attempts. Could you please help me again, I have posted this as a separate question. I have to hand this work in very soon. Thank you so much!

Comment: Working again think it was poor wifi connection